# Easiest server and database services available for deploying an application (AWS specifically)

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, deployment, server

I have written a **real-time** multiplayer game and currently writing its server in NodeJS. I want my game to have login, level up etc, so I need to have a database. This is the first time I am deploying something and I am mostly self taught, so please correct me if I am mixing things up. Since this is my first trial, I do not want to make much commitment right away so I am looking for free options only. And since this should be a real-time game, I need a relatively fast server response. That is why I am looking for the easiest database and server provider that would do and I am aware that with those restrictions I have limited choices and functionality.

As far as I have read online, Heroku seems to be my simplest option for a server (that is why I started writing in NodeJS). However it seems like there is no free database service since all options on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans has monthly fee. I did not want to use Google App Engine since I am new (it certainly is not mentioned as beginner friendly).

So I have found AWS following [Free Cloud Database Service for home development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695771/free-cloud-database-service-for-home-development) post, it seems like I could use Amazon Web Services as a server and database. However most posts I have encountered suggests Google App Engine or Heroku with little mention of AWS. Is this because I am mixing concepts up, or does AWS have drawbacks that I am not aware of? Do you think it is a good idea to use AWS for both as server and database, is it possible to use Heroku as server while using AWS as database or do you have any other suggestion?

Note: Sorry for the question bombardment but those are all related and I am sort of lost in this topic so I had to ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AWS EC2 for the server and RDS for the database. The reason why people use heroku is that it deploys to a custom url very quickly (it's easy to set up). Setting up AWS requires some knowledge of how servers work, but it's not that complicated (and it's free for small apps). Best of luck!

Comment: Do you think it would have problems with real-time applications? And thanks for the support :)

Comment: If you are using Node.js, it's a pinch to use Socket.io to communicate with the server. Basically, the real-time part is dependent on the code, and since you're using Node.js you're fine. It doesn't matter what database you use.  If this comment helped you, please accept it! Thanks :)